# Rails 4 path_to Active Record object of unknown type

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, relative-path, view-helpers

link_to will very cleverly figure out what type an active record object is and create a link to it's show route. How can I find this path for an unknown object type. ie. I'd like something like

```
<div id="target_path" data-path="<%= path_to @my_polymorphic_instance %>" ></div>
```

Implementing this might look something like

```
def path_to obj
  url_for( :controller => obj.class.to_s.underscore.pluralize,
           :action => :show,
           :id => obj.to_param,
           :only_path => true )
end
```

Whats the better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [polymorphic_path](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_path) should do the trick:

```
<div id="target_path" data-path="<%= polymorphic_path @my_polymorphic_instance %>" ></div>
```

In fact, it's source code does something similar to your `path_to` supposition.

Comment: Awesome, I had no idea that was available! I guess I should take more time keeping up with the release notes... ^_^